# How to debug a Vaadin Application in IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, gradle, vaadin

I want to debug a Vaadin 8 app, when I launch the Gradle-Task "vaadinRun" the console tells me the debug port:

> Application running on http://localhost:8080 (debugger on 8000)

Unfortunately IntelliJ doesn't attach the debugger to the port. But is listening on port 65757?
[image: IDEA debug]

---

What works is to attach a remote-debug session to port 8000, but thats odd there must be a simpler way. The question is how?

- IntelliJ IDEA: 2017.2.5
- Gradle: 4.2.1
- Gradle-Vaadin Support: com.devsoap.plugin.vaadin 1.2.5

Comment: You might want to add more informations about your project there.  I assume you are using the de-facto Vaadin Gradle plugin? `plugins { id 'com.devsoap.plugin.vaadin' version '1.2.5' }`

Answer (score 0):

Is only option to connect new Debug Configuration in IntelliJ for Remote and connect it to port 8000? I do not think you can configure port for Groovy plugin in IntelliJ.

You could change Groovy configuration from 8000 to 65757 but I guess that can change.

Comment: Right the port changes, I wonder how can IntelliJ be configured to use always port 8000?

Comment: For Tomcat Run/Debug Configuration you can configure it in Run/Debug Configuration settings. Bug as Groovy Run/Debug Configuration does not expose this setting then I do not know where to change it.

On option might be to see if you can link 2 Run/Debug Configurations together so that you launch Groovy and port 8000 Remote from same task. See "Before launch: Active tool window" and "Run Another Configuration" under plus icon.

Answer (score 0):

Best option for debugging Vaadin app in Intellij is using WAR packaging and deploying app in Tomcat Server.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html

Answer (score 0):

For those using Maven instead of Gradle, i.e. starting the Vaadin appklication with `./mvnw`, you need to set the following env var to activate remote debugging on port 8000:

`export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000"`